# EditorTemplate asp-for="Property" vs value="@Model.Property"

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, asp.net-core-3.0, mvc-editor-templates

I am using .NET Core 3.0 to build a web application which contains an EditorTemplate for a list of values. This EditorTemplate is inside a PartialView. A PartialView is returned from my ActionMethod whenever I add or remove a record from the list.

The confusion is, whenever I remove a record from top/middle of the list, the EditorTemplate is messed up. Please check the images below.

**Question 1:** Why is the happening and how to resolve it?

**Question 2:** Why is value different when I use `<input type="text" asp-for="FilterId" class="form-control" />` & `<input type="text" value="@Model.FilterId" />`

**Before delete**
[image: EditorTemplate before delete]

**After delete**
[image: EditorTemplate after delete]

**AdvancedFilterVM EditorTemplate**

```
@model SSAQ.Web.ViewModels.AdvancedFilterVM

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" asp-for="FilterId" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterId, new { @class="form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.FilterId" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
        <a href="#" class="deleteFilter" data-filterid="@Model.FilterId"><i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**_SurveyFilter PartialView**

```
@model SSAQ.Web.ViewModels.SurveySubmissionViewModel
@if (Model.AdvancedFilter?.Any() == true)
{
<table class="table" id="tblFilter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Using asp-for=FilterId</th>
            <th>Using @@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterId)</th>
            <th>Using value=@@Model.FilterId</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblFilterSurvey">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AdvancedFilter)
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

**JQuery to delete row**

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteFilter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filterId = $(this).data('filterid');
    var formData = $("#formFilter").serializeArray();
    formData.push({ name: 'filterId', value: filterId });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Survey/DeleteFilterRow")',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#filterTableDiv').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**DeleteFilterRow action method**

```
public IActionResult DeleteFilterRow(SurveySubmissionViewModel surveySubmissionVM, Guid filterIdToRemove)
{
    surveySubmissionVM.AdvancedFilter.Remove(surveySubmissionVM.AdvancedFilter.Single(m => m.FilterId == filterIdToRemove));
    return PartialView("_SurveyFilter", surveySubmissionVM);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the same issue. I thought it was caused by cache. But it is not. It really refreshes my knowledge: `EditorFor` renders the template using ModelState prior to Model.

#### Quick fix:

Clear the ModelState before rendering:

```
ModelState.Clear();
return PartialView("_SurveyFilter", surveySubmissionVM);
```

---

#### Further tech info:

Quoted from [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/):

> *ASP.NET MVC assumes ... **Therefore, the Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model**. This enables them to redisplay erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error message if needed.*

There're also some threads online talking about this behavior online:

1. https://forums.asp.net/t/1527149.aspx?A+Bug+EditorFor+and+DisplayFor+don+t+display+same+value+EditorFor+out+of+date
2. [How does Html.EditorFor process changes to the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305572/how-does-html-editorfor-process-changes-to-the-model)
3. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value/
4. https://exceptionnotfound.net/modelstate-values-override-model-values-in-htmlhelpers/

(Although they're all about ASP.NET, the theory applies for ASP.NET Core too)

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, itminus! `ModelState.Clear()` serves the purpose for now. Will look at more elegant way of doing this at the later stage.